# I'm not seeing a past "project" created via console.developers.google.com

Tags: google-app-engine, google-console-developer

When logging into my account via console.developers.google.com, I'm not seeing a past project I created back in 3/2018 specifically for the gmail api.

We are using it specifically for a gmail smtp via a Wordpress plugin, which to my knowledge is still active and working fine. Wondering if anyone experienced a similar issue and how they fixed it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to see the project in the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) ?

Comment: No, it has a different create date and 'enabled api' from the one I'm looking for

Comment: Please, [rise an issue in the issuetracker with your **Project Number**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164)